# Add Statement in high level assembly HLA

Tags: assembly, x86, hla

Hi I just want to add to variable and I can't figure out how to do it.

```
static
input: uns8;
i:real32;
noOfItems: uns8;
```

I want `noOfItems=numberOfItems + i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by first saving the value in the register and then adding it like

```
mov( unitPrice, edx);
add(edx , totalunitPrice );
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the [HLA documentation](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/HighLevelAsm/HLADoc/index.html) before you move any further in your coding.

To increment a variable by 1, you can use the `INC` command:

```
inc( noOfItems )
```

Otherwise use the `ADD` command instead:

```
add( i, noOfItems )
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying but this is not what i was looking for
I have solved it by first saving the value in the register and then adding it like

    mov( i, edx);
    add(edx , numberOfItems );